# Verify the solution of an IVP - missing negative sign?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Thank you in advance for your help.  I probably made a very simple mistake having to do with rules of exponents.

Verify that y = 2 + e^((-x)^3) is the exact solution of the IVP.

Given: y' + 3(x^(2))y = 6x^2; y(0)=3

I'm wondering if there is a typo with "y=2 + e^((-x)^3)" because I solved for an equation and got the same thing without a negative x.  Maybe someone can tell me where I went wrong, because when you plug in the value, the negative does make a difference.

Here's my work:

```
                    dy/dx = 6x^2 - 3(x^2)y     
                    dy/dx = 3x^2(2-y)     
 integral of (1)/(2-y))dy = integral of 3(x^2)dx     
   integral of (1)/(du)du = integral of 3(x^2)dx   where u=2-y and du=-1dy
                   **-**ln|u| = x^3 + c
             e^(ln|u|^**-1**) = e^(x^3 + c)     
                        u = Ce^(x^3)
                      2-y = Ce^(x^3)
                       -y = Ce^(x^3)
                 Ce^(x^3) = y
```

Where did I mess up with the negative sign?  I guess I'm not quite sure what to do with it after the 6th line.

Given y(0)=3...

```
                 Ce^((0)^3) = 3
                     Ce^(0) = 3
                     Ce^(0) = 1
                          C = 1

                       Therefore
                          y = 2 + e^(x(^3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can verify a solution of a differential equation by substituting that solution in to the differential equation and seeing whether the result is true.
In this case $y = 2 + e^{-x^3}$ gives you
$$ y' + 3 x^2 y = -3 x^2 e^{-x^3} + 3 x^2 (2 + e^{-x^3}) = 6 x^2$$
so this is indeed a solution of the differential equation.  Also substitute into the initial condition and you find $y(0) = 3$.  On the other hand, with $2 + e^{x^3}$ you would get 
$$y' + 3 x^2 y = 6 x^2 + 6 x^2 e^{x^3}$$

EDIT: If $-\ln |2-y| = -\ln |u| = x^3 + c$, 
you should have $ |2-y| = \exp(-x^3 - c)$ and so $2 - y = C \exp(-x^3)$ with
$C = \pm e^{-c}$.
I don't know why you dropped that $-$ sign.

Comment: Thanks, and I get substituting the equation back in.  But what about the negative, do you have any idea where I lost that?